# Cannot POST correctly when submitting form in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to upload files (specifically images) to a database. When I try to `POST` my form in `profile_photo.html` (attached below), it gives me an error saying: 
`MultiValueDictKeyError at /user_profile/login/upload_profile_photo/`

profile_photo.html:

```
<body>
<div id="blue_background_with_fibers">
    <form class="pull-center white form-signin" role="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %} {{ form.as_p }}
        <button class="aqua button2" type="submit" value="OK">Upload</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

detail.html that uses profile_photo.html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="profile" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Upload Profile Picture</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <!--Insert form here-->
                    <iframe src="upload_profile_photo/" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" width="560px" height="175px"></iframe>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <span>Ekho © 2016</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I believe that I am messing up in my `views.py` (specifically under the `EditProfileView` class). Below is my views.py:

```
class EditProfileView(View):
form_class = EditProfileForm

def get(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(None);
    return render(request, 'ekho/profile_photo.html', {'form': form})

def post(self, request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'ekho/login.html')
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.user = request.user
            user.profile_photo = request.FILES['profile_photo']
            file_type = user.profile_photo.url.split('.')[-1]
            file_type = file_type.lower()
            if file_type not in IMAGE_FILE_TYPES:
                context = {
                    'user': user,
                    'form': form,
                    'error_message': 'Image file must be PNG, JPG, or JPEG',
                }
                return render(request, 'ekho/detail.html', context)
            user.save()
            return render(request, 'ekho/login.html', {'user': user})
        return render(request, 'ekho/detail.html', {"form": form,})
```

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile');
    background = models.FileField(upload_to = 'user_profile/media/', blank=True, null=True);
    profile = models.FileField(upload_to = 'user_profile/media/', blank=True, null=True);
    about = models.TextField(default='', blank=True);
    reviews = models.TextField(default='', blank=True);

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

And finally urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'user_profile'

urlpatterns = [
# /user_profile/
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

# /user_profile/username
url(r'^user_profile/detail/$', views.detail, name='detail'),

# user_profile/register/
url(r'^register/$', views.RegisterFormView.as_view(), name='register'),

# user_profile/login/
url(r'^login/$', views.LoginFormView.as_view(), name='login'),

url(r'^login/upload_profile_photo/$', views.EditProfileView.as_view(), name='edit_profile')
```

]

Comment: would you please attach your stack track as well? it would help to investigate which line prompt you the error

Comment: The code to check the file type should really be in the form itself, in a clean_fieldname method.

Comment: @Enix 

You can view the stack stace here: http://dpaste.com/1MPBNY4#

Comment: you have two files to upload right? did you upload the images at the same time? the error seems coming from the statement `request.FILES['profile']`, and key is not found in `request.FILES` dict.

Comment: @Enix Actually what happened was I forgot to upload both files at the same time. But now I am getting this other error where it cannot save the user associated with the account here: 
http://dpaste.com/1NBRP9V

This is the error it returns: `UNIQUE constraint failed: user_profile_userprofile.user_id`

Comment: did you save your `UserProfile` model twice in your view?

Comment: @Enix What do you exactly mean by that. I only have it saved once, you can confirm by looking at my `views.py` code above. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

This but be the problem
In your views.py file you are trying to access 'profile_photo' which should have been in 'profile' according to your models.py

views.py

```
user.profile_photo = request.FILES['profile_photo']
```

This error `MultiValueDictKeyError` occurs when you try to access the key that is not available in Dict

I guess this should work

views.py

```
user.profile_photo = request.FILES['profile']
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this mistake out that solved the MultiKeyDictError, however I am now getting a new problem where it cannot save the changes made. This happens when I write `user.save()` in `views.py`. The specific error it returns is `UNIQUE constraint failed: user_profile_userprofile.user_id`

Answer (score 0):

PyMentor has a grate tutorial to post form with image in django.
http://pymentor.in/upload-image-file-using-django/

Answer (score 0):

For your second problem: `UNIQUE constraint failed: user_profile_userprofile.user_id`

You can't use `form.save` to retrieve the `UserProfile` instance. It will create **another** user profile object after calling `form.save`, so you will get `UNIQUE constraint error`.

Try to replace `form.save` with:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk).profile
```